# GNU Build system que

Tags: gcc

I am building my project along with the 3rd party library.

They have used asm blocks,

Here are the compiler flags am using.

-pedantic -pipe -Wundef -Wall -Wchar-subscripts -Wsign-compare -Wno-missing-braces -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fno-inline -std=c99-g -O2

GCC throws "asm" undeclared error.

Can you please let me know which flag is causing this?

Dinesh P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `-std=c99` , there's no inline assembly in C99. You could perhaps use `-std=gnu99`

Comment: Thanks... 
Is there a way to conditionally remove a flag in particular Makefile.am and add new flag in the same.